# Can't fix GPG Error NO_PUB_KEY

Tags: apt, updates, ppa

As the title, I have the so common "GPG Error...NO_PUB_KEY" error, but I'm not able to fix it at all. 
I tried both `Y PPA Manager` and the command line `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <PUB_KEY>` but it doesn't work; indeed, the last one always returns something like that

```
gpg: key 98AB5139: "Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

The problem started when I modified the `sources.list` file to delete two lines regarding a `dropbox` ppa. From that time on, I've begun to have a lot of GPG errors.

```
W: GPG error: http://deb.torproject.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 74A941BA219EC810
W: GPG error: http://download.virtualbox.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 54422A4B98AB5139
W: GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 13B00F1FD2C19886
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A040830F7FAC5991
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://desktop-download.mendeley.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D800C7D66F036044
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://packages.ntop.org x64/ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 98C843C67921DF34

W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://packages.ntop.org all/ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 98C843C67921DF34

W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32

W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://linux.dropbox.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FC918B335044912E
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ntop.org/apt-stable/14.04/x64/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ntop.org/apt-stable/14.04/all/InRelease  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Even restoring the file using the `sources.list.save` file hasn't worked until now. However, to be honest, I don't know why this change should broken all the stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `apt` can handle only <40 sources and I've hit the limit.

The most efficient solution to me is to delete some unuseful `.list*` files from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and `.gpg*` from `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d`.

Although I hit the limit long time ago, I thik the problem has only arosen now because today I tried to "Import all missing keys" with `Y PPA Manager`. I mean, maybe I had some PPA without any GPG key, I don't know.

If someone else knows a different workaround, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This workaround may help you:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists /var/apt/lists.old
mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Why this should help? I'm not criticizing, just curious on what I will do.

Comment: Yes, they will clean your apt-get caches and redo the cached lists. This should work.

Comment: And why the `partial` folder? Btw it doesn't work and I think I figured out the problem.

Comment: `mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial` is to create 2 directories /var/lib/apt/lists and its sub directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial. It's not about partial. As move /var/lib/apt/lists to a backup directory, we have to recreate its sub directory too.